# Get checkbox values without Id JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am iterating through a dynamically created table which has rows that contain plain text, checkboxes, and select drop down boxes. While iterating through the table with

```
$('#myTableId td').each ->
  thisSelect = $(this).find("option:selected").text()
  if thisSelectBox != ""
    allSelectValues.splice selectCounter,0, thisSelectBox
    selectCounter++
```

So this code works to get my select values, and I am using a similar approach for the text boxes. My issue though is getting the checkbox values. Since the table is dynamically created, I cant get the checkbox values by id since the table is dynamically created and when I try to use this code:

```
$('#tableId td').each ->
   thisCheckbox = $(this).find("input.classNameOfCheckbox:checkbox").val()
```

It returns "on" when iterating on a td that contains a checkbox whether or not it was checked. So my question is what is the best approach for this problem?

Comment: Hi check out .prop http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

Just add [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to the end of your selector and it will only select those elements that are checked/selected

```
$(this).find("input.classNameOfCheckbox:checkbox:checked").val()
```

If none are checked, you will get `undefined`.

And if there is more than one checkbox checked in the td .val() will return only the first one's value. You would need to use `.each` or similar looping method to get each value

Demo

```js
jQuery(document.body).append(      
  "Checked: "+jQuery("div").find("input:checkbox:checked").val() 
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="first" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="second" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" value="third" />
</div>
```